# Error starting webapp with Mybatis, c3p0 on Tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat, mybatis, c3p0, tomcat8

I am trying to deploy my webapp on **Tomcat 8** that uses **Mybatis 3.2.7** and **c3p0** for connection pooling to connect to an **SQLServer** database. I have the sqljdbc4.jar in my classpath. I query the database during my webapp startup to get some values.

The application works in Tomcat 7, however on Tomcat 8, I cannot connect to the database. I debugged a lot using eclipse and the root cause is in the file `BasicResourcePool.class` file in c3p0 where it is waiting for resource to become available but then throws an `java.lang.InterruptedException`.

Due to this, Mybatis is throwing a `java.SQL.SQLException` and thus my webapp does not start as it cannot connect to the database.

Has someone else upgraded to Tomcat 8 and has successfully used Mybatis-c3p0? If yes am I missing something over here?

Comment: the root cause is whoever / whatever is calling interrupt() on your wait()ing Threads (and perhaps the condition that causes them to wait() so long that something decides to interrupt them).

Comment: @SteveWaldman can we know somehow via debugging what is interrupting?

Comment: Unfortunately, not very easily. Putting aside the constraints of any security policy you might impose, anything can get access to a Thread and call its interrupt() method. Maybe in your debugger you could put watches on calls to that method, or search your codebase for them. Otherwise, it's likely that interrupt() gets called in response to long waits, you might try to resolve the conditions or settings that have your clients in prolonged waits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this. It was JDBC driver issue. Mybatis isn't very good in showing underlying exceptions it seems.

Found this on tomcat 8's documentation:

> Thus, the web applications that have database drivers in their
>   WEB-INF/lib directory cannot rely on the service provider mechanism
>   and should register the drivers explicitly.

So, I added a `Class.forName()` with the appropriate driverClass during app startup and this solved my issue.